# Get username from ActiveXObject("WScript.Network") not working?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I need a way to get a User's name from a web application that will be used in FireFox, Chrome, and IE. I have a javascript function in my code that is the onclick function for a button. The button is supposed to show an alert with the user's name. For some reason this is not working in my code. I am debugging in Visual Studio 2015, and I have opened VS as an administrator. I am attempting to run this code in Firefox and IE and nothing shows up. Is there another way to do this? Am I doing this wrong?

My HTML Code

```
<button onclick="getUser()">GET USER</button>
<script>
function getUser() {
    var net = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
    alert(net.username);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you found the solution for this problem ? If so please post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveX is a technology that was only ever supported in Internet Explorer and which isn't supported in the most recent versions of that browser.

There is no standard way to get information about the system username of the browser user from a webpage.